# How to aggregate MySQL table data by half-year?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, group-by

Can someone help me write a MySQL query in for dividing the data based on Half-Yearly having records having column in Date format?

I wrote the Query for GROUP by Monthly and Quarterly but Half-Yearly is not happening.

I used the following query for weekly, monthly and quarterly:

```
CREATE view darren_inventory_mrp_forecast_summary as
    ( SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY sub.product_id) as id,
             SUM(sub.quantity)/12 as quantity,
             SUM(sub2.quantity)/4 as quarterly,
             SUM(sub3.quantity)/51 as weekly,
             sub.product_id as product_id FROM
          (SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product_id) as id,
                  product_id as product_id,
                  SUM(product_qty) as quantity
          FROM stock_move
          WHERE consumed_for IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY to_char(DATE(create_date), 'YYYY-MM'), product_id 
          ) 
      as sub 
      LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product_id) as id,
                  product_id as product_id,
                  SUM(product_qty) as quantity
          FROM stock_move
          WHERE consumed_for IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY to_char(DATE(create_date), 'YYYY-Q'), product_id 
          ) 
      as sub2 on (sub2.product_id=sub.product_id)  
      LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product_id) as id,
                  product_id as product_id,
                  SUM(product_qty) as quantity
          FROM stock_move
          WHERE consumed_for IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY to_char(DATE(create_date), 'YYYY-WW'), product_id 
          ) 
      as sub3 on (sub3.product_id=sub.product_id)  
      GROUP BY sub.product_id
    )
```

Comment: Why didn't your code work for half-yearly if you have it working for quarterly? Post your code! What happens when you run it?

Comment: What about GROUP BY yearOf(timestamp), monthOf(timestamp)>6 ? Of course yearOf and monthOf functions aren't okay, you have to find their working syntax in the docs.

Comment: Updated the question.. now i want to find the same for Half yearly

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the month in which a date item occurs with this.

```
select last_day(datecolumn) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month
```

You can get the month of the year of a date item with this

```
select month(datecolumn)
```

You can get the number of months into the half-year (0-5) like this

```
select (month(datecolumn) -1) mod 6
```

So, you can get the first day of the half-year like this.

```
select last_day(datecolumn) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month
        - interval (month(datecolumn) -1) mod 6 month
```

Then you can GROUP BY that big expression and summarize your data that way.

This also works:

```
select last_day(datecolumn) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month
      - interval (quarter(datecolumn) -1) mod 2 quarter
```

The trick is to come up with an expression that truncates any datetime expression to the first day of the half-year in which it lies.

If you want to handle just stuff from particular years, do something like this.

```
  WHERE datecolumn >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y-01-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND datecolumn >  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

This particular example chooses everything in the calendar years 2015 and 2016. The expression `DATE_FORMAT(someTimestampValue, '%y-01-01')` truncates a date or datetime value to the beginning of the calendar year.

Comment: is it possible to add a where clause for last 12 months, so that it gives me the result based on the past 12 months

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple method for grouping by half year.

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY year(date_column), CEILING(MONTH(date_column)/6)
```

For the months January (1) - June (6) the following equals 1.

For the months July (7) - December (12) the following equals 2.

```
CEILING(MONTH(date_column)/6)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no half_year function in MySql, but you can calculate it from quarter:
**floor(quarter(date_column) / 3)** 
This one returns 0 for 1,2 quarter and 1 for 3,4 quarter.

So to group by half-year:

```
GROUP BY year(date_column) + 0.1 * floor(quarter(date_column) / 3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this first by grouping by year, then aggregating the quarters so that quarter 1 and 2 return 1 and 3 and 4 return 2.

```
GROUP BY YEAR(date_column), CEILING(QUARTER(date_column) / 2)
```

If you only want to group by the half year being 1 or 2, you can skip the YEAR(date_column) part.